# Detect a knot from its fundamental group

Tags: fundamental-groups, knot-theory, braid-groups

I'm studying the braid closure and I ended up with the knot $K= (\sigma_1\,\sigma_2\,\sigma_1\,\sigma_2\,\sigma_1)_*$, here the notation is according Murasugi but it does not really matter. By using a Snappy software, I know that the fundamental group of $K$ has the following presentation
$$
\pi_1(S^3 \setminus K) = \langle\, a,b \mid ab^2=b^2a \,\rangle,
$$
thus $K$ is not trivial. Snappy doesn't recognize $K$, which means that $K$ is a composite know (i.e. is not prime). My questions are:

```
Which knot is K? Can I find its prime factors (i.e K1#K2 = K)?
```

and

```
For a generic K, is there a way to detect K's name from its fundamental group?
```

Comment: How do you know it is composite and not just a non-hyperbolic knot?  SnapPy also has trouble identifying torus knots, so you might just have an unusual presentation for a common knot.  Last, are you sure it is a knot and not a link?  If it is a knot, then it must be a prime knot, as a consequence of Stallings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: In the braid group on three strands, $\sigma_1 \, \sigma_2 \, \sigma_1 = \sigma_2 \, \sigma_1 \, \sigma_2$,
so your braid is equivalent to
$$
\sigma_1 \, (\sigma_1 \, \sigma_2 \, \sigma_1) \, \sigma_1 
= \sigma_1^2 \, \sigma_2 \, \sigma_1^2.
$$
By Markov's theorem, you can cyclically permute the the braid word without changing the link closure, so
$$
\bigl( \sigma_1^2 \, \sigma_2 \, \sigma_1^2 \bigr)_* 
= \bigl( \sigma_1^2 \, \sigma_1^2 \, \sigma_2 \bigr)_* 
= \bigl( \sigma_1^4 \, \sigma_2 \bigr)_*.
$$
Using the other Markov move (stabilization), the closure of $\sigma_1^4 \, \sigma_2$ in $B_3$ is isotopic to the closure of $\sigma_1^4$ in $B_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (just twists of two strands).

This particular $4$-twist link is sometimes called [Solomon's knot](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Solomon%27s_knot) despite not being a knot by mathematical definitions. (It's a two component link.)

Comment: Thank you @samny. Do you moreover know a way to detect a knot’s name from it's fundamental group? Obviously, I expected an answer only for “simple” knots (I.e. with low crossing number)

Comment: There are results bounding the number of possible knots with isomorphic fundamental groups (but these are about knots, i.e. $1$-component links) in terms of the number of prime factors: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-080-01/S0002-9939-1980-0574528-5/S0002-9939-1980-0574528-5.pdf

Comment: And the *word problem* and *conjugacy problem* is solved for fundamental groups of knots in the overlapping classes of tame, prime, or alternating. In other words, given a finite presentation (e.g. Wirtinger presentation): https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-030-01/S0002-9939-1971-0279169-X/S0002-9939-1971-0279169-X.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Given the braid presentation, I drew the knot in [Knotfolio](https://kmill.github.io/knotfolio/):

[image]

It was recognized as the prime link [L4a1](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/L4a1), which the other answer points out is known as "Solomon's knot" (though in knot theory only one-component links are called "knots"). In particular, as an oriented link it is [L4a1{1}](https://linkinfo.sitehost.iu.edu/diagram_display.php?L4a1%7B1%7D) and not [L4a1{0}](https://linkinfo.sitehost.iu.edu/diagram_display.php?L4a1%7B0%7D).

Supposing it's prime, this is the only 2-component link with up to 5 crossings with the same Jones polynomial and Alexander polynomial, so Knotfolio has correctly identified it. The diagram, through Seifert's algorithm, gives a Seifert surface of genus 1 ("can. genus" in Knotfolio) so the link is indeed prime.