# How to know if a group is the fundamental group of a knot complement and if so how would you reconstruct the original knot from it?

Tags: group-theory, knot-theory

The following question finds the knot from a given fundamental group.

[Detect a knot from its fundamental group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249677/detect-a-knot-from-its-fundamental-group)

However my question is oriented into generally verifying if any given group is the fundamental group of a knot. And if it is what would be the process to reconstruct the knot from its given fundamental group.

Comment: (+1) I would also be interested in an abstract characterization of when a group is the fundamental group of (the complement of) some knot. One thing to be wary of, though, is that we _can't_ reconstruct the knot from the group in general. For instance, the square knot and the granny knot are inequivalent, but have the same knot group. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_group) for more.

Comment: Thank you! just did some edits based on your insights, it was the knot complement what I was interested in.

Comment: How is your group supposed to be given? If by a finite presentation then it's totally hopeless.

Comment: If you know, additionally, that your group is the fundamental groups of an (unspecified) compact 3-dimensional manifold, then this could be doable but quite long and I am not sure about the motivation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [Adian-Rabin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adian%E2%80%93Rabin_theorem), there is no algorithm to find out if a finitely presented group is a knot group: being a knot group is an abstract property, there are knot groups (say, $\mathbb Z$), and there are finitely presented groups which cannot embed into a knot group (see, for example, Prop 1.1 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-14/issue-4/H_2-of-subgroups-of-knot-groups/10.1215/ijm/1256052960.pdf)).

Comment: Just to give a concrete example of Prop 1.1 of a finitely presented group that can't embed in a knot group: the free abelian group on three generators $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

Comment: @KyleMiller: The group of order $2$ is another concrete example.